# How to make one subquery from 2 queries in sqlalchemy orm?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I just start to study sqlalchemy orm and need to combine 2 queries and make only one. They are complicated so I confused to make just only one.

```
query_first = DB_SESSION.query(
            AllFlats, distance, ppm
        ).filter(
            or_(
                AllFlats.is_apart == False,
                AllFlats.is_apart == None
            ),
            distance < data['radius'],
        )

query_second = DB_SESSION.query(BlackList).filter(BlackList.is_final == is_final).all()
```

Both tables have similar columns:

url = Column(VARCHAR(255), index=True, unique=True)

external_id = Column(VARCHAR(255), unique=True)

query_first - its all data about rooms. Query_second - rooms which are in black list. I need subtract from the first list of apartments from the second.

thanks a lot.

I make such query:

```
query = DB_SESSION.query(AllFlats, distance, BlackList).filter(
            and_(
                AllFlats.url == BlackList.url,
                BlackList.is_final == True,
                or_(
                    AllFlats.is_apart == False,
                    AllFlats.is_apart == None
                ),
                # distance < data['analogsFilters']['radius'],
            )
        ).all()
```

But it returns list of tuples and I need to get class 'sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query'

Comment: Are you saying you don't actually want to RUN the query?

Comment: Inside the program it will run during filtering data.

Comment: Then shouldn't you just remove the `.all()`?

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I dont know why, but it works :)

Comment: The `DB_SESSION.query` function creates a query object, but doesn't do anything with it.  The `.all()` function runs the query and returns the results to you.